# PostgreSQL extract Year fromDate variable

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I would like to extract the year from my date type column,
i used the extract function. But it can't accept my column as a source,
Find below my Query

```
SELECT NO_PTF, (select extract(year from timestamp C.DT_CRS)::int) as NO_AEE, MT_PRF
  FROM public.perfcumultb C
       INNER JOIN
      (SELECT DT_CRS -- Date maxi pour chaque année
          FROM ( SELECT (select extract(year from timestamp DT_CRS)::int) as ANNEE, MAX(DT_CRS) AS DT_CRS
                  FROM public.perfcumultb 
                  GROUP BY (select extract(year from timestamp DT_CRS)::int)) C
              )        Q ON C.DT_CRS = Q.DT_CRS;
```

I know when i replace DT_CRS by '2006-01-05' it's run without error. But here i need to keep the column
Someone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
(select extract(year from timestamp c.dt_crs)::int) as no_aee
```

Should most likely be simplified as:

```
extract(year from c.dt_crs) as no_aee
```

That is:

- no need for a sub-`select`
- the `timestamp` keyword is meant to declare *literal* timestamps; if `dt_crs` is not of a timestamp datatype, you can cast it with `dt_crs::timestamp`, but I assume it is of the correct datatype already
- `extract()` returns an integer value, no need to cast it

I also strongly suspect that your query can be simplified. It *looks* like you want the row with the latest date for each year. If so, use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (extract(year from dt_crs)) c.*
from public.perfcumultb c
order by extract(year from dt_crs), dt_crs desc
```

Comment: I need to cast to int because extract() return a double precision